# Determine the transfer function, the impulse response function and give a formula for solving the following initial value problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$y''-4y'+5y=g(t);\quad y(0)=0,~y'(0)=1$$
Knowing the initial values of $y(x)$ and $y'(x)$ it's easy to take the $\mathcal{L}$ on both sides of the equation:
$$\mathcal{L}\left\lbrace y''-4y'+5y\right\rbrace=\mathcal{L}\left\lbrace g(t) \right\rbrace$$
And this results on:
$$\mathcal{L}\left\lbrace y\right\rbrace=\frac{\mathcal{L}\left\lbrace g(t) \right\rbrace+1}{(s^{2}-4s+5)}$$
without knowing $g(t)$, how should I proceed? Also, how exactly is the transfer function and the impulse response function calculated?

Comment: The transfer function assumes zero initial condition. In particular, above you have $\hat{h}(s) = { 1\over s^2-4s+5}$.

Answer (score 0):

From the general context of exercises of this kind you know that $g(t)=0$ for $t<0$, as all dynamical components are considered "switched off" for $t<0$ and activated at $t=0$.

Set $u(t)=e^{-2t}y(t)$ to find
$$
u''(t)+u(t)=e^{-2t}(y''(t)-4y'(t)+5y(t))=e^{-2t}g(t)=h(t).
$$
The general solution formula for the harmonic oscillator
$$
u(t)=u(0)\cos(t)+u'(0)\sin(t)+\int_0^t\sin(t-s)h(s)\,ds
$$
then translates to
$$
y(t)=e^{2t}\sin(t)+\int_0^te^{2(t-s)}\sin(t-s)g(s)\,ds.
$$
You could also read this off the Laplace transform formula by completing the square in $s^2-4s+5=(s-2)^2+1$.